# Datalist records line in vertical direction

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a Datalist. I have 20 records and 1 columns per record to show in datalist.

How can I display each 15 records in vertical line. I mean if the total records are 16 then first 15 should come vertically in first line and next 16th record will come in next line.
In case the the total records comes out to be 12 then all records should come in center line vertically

My Code

```
<div style="overflow:auto; height: 230px; width:340px;">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="0px" ItemStyle-Width="340px"
        RepeatDirection="Vertical">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAreas" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `RepeatDirection.Vertical` and set `RepeatColumns` to `(records / 15) + 1` and add `15 - (records % 15)` empty records to your existing records.

**EDIT:** Who ever downvoted me, care to leave an explanation, or is the logic simply to much for you? You don't have to add empty records if there are 15 or less existing records, but if there are more - this method always displays 15 rows per column, and a required number of columns - you just have to style the empty cells (which come as last cells in the last column) the same as the background, or just make them transparent.

Comment: `and add 15 - (records % 15)` Why?

Comment: @PankajGarg if you have 16 records, then datalist will display them as two columns with 8 rows - if you have (15 - (16 % 15)) + 16 = (15 - 1) + 16 = 14 + 16 = 30 rows, then datalist will display them as two columns with 15 rows each (second to fifteenth row in second column will be empty - exactly as you want it)... you don't need to add empty records if there are 15 or less existing ones

Comment: BUT i don't want to display empty record.

Comment: @PankajGarg just style them to look like a background - do I have to draw everything for you...

Comment: If I have 16 record then first column should display 15 rows and second should display 1

Comment: @PankajGarg - to quote myself "(second to fifteenth row in second column will be empty - exactly as you want it)" - come on man, make an effort here, this means the same as "If I have 16 record then first column should display 15 rows and second should display 1"...